# Are there any API's that'll let me search by image?

Tags: image, api, information-retrieval, content-based-retrieval

I have an image and I want to search to see what it is. Any API's available for that?

Comment: I use www.tineye.com for this.  Works great!

Comment: [Google Image Search](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/searchbyimage.html) does this to an extent. However, there seems to be no API for this (yet?).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe there are quite a few. You want to search for [Content-based Image Retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-based_image_retrieval) (CBIR). Wikipedia has a page of [CBIR engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CBIR_Engines), including an extensive list of open source ones. For example, [isk-daemon](http://www.imgseek.net/isk-daemon) and [LIRE](http://www.semanticmetadata.net/lire/) are both open source CBIR libraries:

> isk-daemon is an open source standalone server and library capable of
>   adding content-based (visual) image searching to any image related
>   website or software.

---

> The LIRE (Lucene Image REtrieval) library provides a simple way to
>   retrieve images and photos based on their color and texture
>   characteristics.

Answer (score 2):

Another one is  [fire](http://code.google.com/p/fire-cbir/) it's  GPL and they use the Magick++ libraries.